# What is the selectizeInput limit for R Shiny and how can it be optimized for 200K ids?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I have a application where my dataframe is having a list of 200K ids and trying to pass them in my selectizeinput **choices**`(choices = sort(unique(data$id)))` parameter for user selection, while doing so when I launch the application it gets crashed without any error.
Also, I got some warning messages :

**Warning**: the select input "id" contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.

```
pageUI <- function (id) {
  ns <- NS(id)  
  tagList(
    
    uiOutput(ns('select_id'))
    
  )
}

pageserver <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- NS("pageserver")
  
  data <- data.frame(df)
  
  output$select_id <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput(inputId = ns("Id"),
                   label = 'Dropdown Shows first 5 Id',
                   choices = sort(unique(data$id)),
                   options = list(maxOptions = 5, placeholder = 'Enter Id'),
                   width = '100%')
  })
  
  
}
```

While trying to find the root cause I could see the threshold is max till 60K in choices

```
choices = sort(unique(head(data$id, 63000)))
```

argument but loading time is on higher side but beyond that it's not working.

```
pageserver <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- NS("pageserver")  # id is the namespace identifier, create namespace function (all Input/Output ids below must be wrapped in ns())
  
  data <<- data.frame("somedata")
  
  output$select_id <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput(inputId = ns("Id"),
                   label = 'Dropdown Shows first 5 Id',
                   choices = sort(unique(head(data$id,63000))),
                   options = list(maxOptions = 5, placeholder = 'Enter Id'),
                   width = '100%')
  })
}
```

Does Selectizeinput have limit in number of choices or is there any better way to approach this problem.

Comment: One can change the limit. It is 1000 by default but beyond 1000 this is not reasonable. I invite you to follow the warning message: **consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.**

Comment: Indeed, server-side is the way to go here. You'd add those choices via `updateSelectizeInput(..., server = TRUE)` in the `server` of the app.